# Vuetify (1.x) Data Table low performance during pagination

Tags: vue.js, performance, datatable, frontend, vuetify.js

I have redesigned an existing data table so that, instead of bunching up unrelated information in a single column, there are more columns per row, and most of them are sortable now.

After the redesign, paginating in a data table (25 or 50 rows / page), the browser now locks up for about 3-5 seconds instead of being less than 1 second.

The items of the tables come from a computed property. I was going to try optimizing the calculation of the computed value, but when paginating, the computed property doesn't get recalculated, so I don't see a point of doing that. I don't know how else I can speed things up again.

Comment: vuetify 1.x LTS ended nearly 2.5 years ago.  probably not the answer you want but you should heavily consider upgrading.  2.x or even 3.x will most likely not even have such a problem.

Comment: Sadly, the decision to upgrade is not in my hands, but in upper management's. Will upgrading actually fix or at least alleviate the mentioned issue? If so, I might try to convince the management to put some time into upgrading.

Comment: 1.x is dead at this point.  You could make a strong case that any software your team uses should be actively supported by a development team at the very least for bugs and security issues.  A lot of the core Vuetify code was rewritten in 2.0.0 as noted in the [original release notes](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/releases/tag/v2.0.0), plus they've been releasing updates to fix bugs and others issues for 2.x for over 2 years now making it incredibly stable. I would be very surprised if your performance issues carry over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

Putting the data that feeds the table into variable `rows` in `data()` rather than in a computed property made everything a lot faster.

In my case, there are only a handful places that necessitate a recalculation of the table data, so I added a `tableUpdated()` method which will update `rows` whenever I need.

This change made not only pagination, but also chaging rows per page, dynamically adding/removing columns, and search filtering a lot faster.